# Realm of the Elderlings tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

We currently have several tags related to Robin Hobb's main fantasy series, *The Realm of the Elderlings*. This series consists of several smaller series. The following three have their own tags:

- The Rain Wilds Chronicles: [rain-wilds-chronicles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rain-wilds-chronicles) (1 question)
- The Fitz and the Fool Trilogy: [fitz-and-the-fool](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fitz-and-the-fool) (1 question)
- The Tawny Man Trilogy: [tawny-man-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tawny-man-series) (1 question)

Several of the series do *not* have their own tags:

- The Farseer Trilogy (the first one).
- The Liveship Traders Trilogy

We have questions that could certainly be tagged as [farseer-trilogy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/farseer-trilogy), but probably not any that need a [liveship-traders](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liveship-traders) tag.

We also lack a tag for the series as a whole, i.e. [realm-of-the-elderlings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/realm-of-the-elderlings). Since each of the subseries has only a single question, and two are the same, there's an argument that they are too granular. Of course, there are  a few questions that are (probably not [correctly](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/51379)) tagged as [robin-hobb](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robin-hobb) that could use a series tag.

So, should we:

1. Make a [realm-of-the-elderlings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/realm-of-the-elderlings) tag, and stick it on all the  questions about the subseries, but keep the series tags?
2. Make a [realm-of-the-elderlings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/realm-of-the-elderlings) tag, and stick it on all the  questions about the subseries, but not keep the series tags?
3. Keep the series tags, and not make a [realm-of-the-elderlings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/realm-of-the-elderlings) tag?

Comment: These tags are a mess and this level of granularity is totally unwarranted for single questions. Just dump **all** of the franchise questions under a single tag (realm-of-the-elderlings) and delete everything else.

Comment: @Valorum - The question is  a mess, or the tags  are? Anyway, maybe you could turn that into an answer.

Comment: @Valorum If there's enough meta consensus in favour of your suggestion, it can be done by mods without bumping any questions to the front page.

Comment: @randal'thor - Can mods make tag edits without bumping?

Comment: @Valorum No, but we can **merge** tags. In this case, merging all three existing tags into [tag:realm-of-the-elderlings] would have the desired effect.

Comment: @Valorum - Could you post your suggestion as an answer? It seems good to me, but I'd rather see what the community thinks (as would Rand, it seems). Or, if you would rather not, I could post it, I suppose.

Comment: @Adamant - Done and done. Now watch it get downvoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These books are not nearly popular enough to merit individual property tags when they're basically part of a unified book series created by a single author.

I suggest we create a **[realm-of-the-elderlings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/realm-of-the-elderlings)** tags and dump all of the questions about this series **into that tag**, then delete/remove all of the other tags; [rain-wilds-chronicles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rain-wilds-chronicles), [fitz-and-the-fool](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fitz-and-the-fool), [tawny-man-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tawny-man-series), [farseer-trilogy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/farseer-trilogy) and [robin-hobb](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robin-hobb).

If we can do so in such a way as to not disfigure the front page, that would be just peachy.

Comment: +5/-0 seems like a pretty good consensus. **I've created a [tag:realm-of-the-elderlings] tag and merged the three existing subseries tags into it.** I left the [tag:robin-hobb] tag alone, since she's apparently written books which aren't part of the RotE series, so it's worth keeping an author tag as well.