# Why were these "superman-brainiac-attacks" tags removed?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I noticed that the "superman-brainiac-attacks" tag has being removed from several of my questions (A low rep user suggested it and it was approved by high rep users). Examples:

[Why did Lex Luthor tell Mercy to call his attorney?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43669/why-did-lex-luthor-tell-mercy-to-call-his-attorney)

[How did Superman return from the Phantom Zone?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43668/how-did-superman-return-from-the-phantom-zone)

**Why is that? What's wrong with this tag?**

Comment: Do we specifically need a tag for a single animated Superman film with practically no questions about it; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_Brainiac_Attacks

Comment: @Valorum Yes, [every specific work can get its own specific tag](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/31178), no matter how many or few questions we have about it. It hurts nothing, and it improves finding related questions later if there's ever a jump in popularity due to something like a re-release or some viral article.

Comment: @Valorum Why not. There are lots of tags which target only one movie. For example, "doctor-strange-2016". Also, low number of questions doesn't mean it can't receive questions in future. I actually followed it.

Comment: Fair enough. I've not got a dog in this fight. It seems a perfectly valid tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see no good reason why these tags should have been removed. We've discussed this issue before and the consensus opinion was that single-work tags are perfectly acceptable.

[What is the correct usage of individual works tags vs. author tags vs. franchise tags?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7923/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-individual-works-tags-vs-author-tags-vs-franchise/7924#7924)

---

I've re-added your original tags as well as creating a tag wiki to explain what they're referring to.

Comment: Yup, I think this was just removed in accident, as part of the big editing event that recently occurred, possibly because there may not have been enough (or any?) tag wiki excerpt or tag wiki on the tag to begin with.

Comment: @CreationEdge - That was my first thought. Someone just tidied it without thinking. No conspiracy, just overzealousness.

Answer (score 4):

Given that @Valorum has sorted this I just wanted to add my apology for removing these tags in the first place. I assume I mis-clicked when I was re-tagging the questions during the editing and didn't realise it. Once again, sorry.