# The chronicles of [riddick]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed [Why did Riddick save the pup?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157633/why-did-riddick-save-the-pup) was tagged [riddick](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddick), but this seems to violate the general SFF taxonomy. The full series is called [The Chronicles of Riddick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Riddick_(franchise)), which is also (confusingly) the title of the second film.

I propose making [riddick](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddick) (2) and [pitch-black](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pitch-black) (1) synonyms of [the-chronicles-of-riddick](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-chronicles-of-riddick) and editing the tag to indicate that this one tag covers the entire series. Burninating the tags wouldn't stop people from creating them in the future.

Comment: `riddick` and `pitch-black` are pretty useless, apparently. 2 questions between them, and one is on hold... yikes.

Comment: Why not just do this, `the-chronicles-of-riddick-2000` and `the-chronicles-of-riddick-2004` and `the-chronicles-of-riddick-2013` ?

Comment: @KyloRen - But what about the cartoon prequel, the comic series, the novel and the video games?

Comment: The one appropriate name for this question is "The chronicles of [riddick]".

Comment: We have [Narnia], too, whose full name is *The Chronicles of Narnia*. You can probably find lots more examples. The SFF tags are a mess; always have been.

Comment: IMHO a single tag `the-chronicles-of-riddick` is not a good match for the entire Riddick franchise, since it's the title of one film. People might get confused. So why not simply `riddick` for an umbrella tag? Oh, wait.

Comment: @Mithrandir I probably should have been clearer. While [riddick] might be simpler (if we were making it today I'd go with that) [the-chronicles-of-riddick] has the most questions of the three tags

Comment: [riddick] is also the name of a character _and_ a movie (the third in the franchise).

Comment: how about [the-pitch-black-world-of-riddick] ;) j/k

Comment: @nkcampbell The fast and the riddick?

Comment: @Machavity - This comment chain has gone from the sublime to the Riddick(ulus)

Comment: @Valorum [Riddikulus!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doxxfXqpKYA)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No, let's not violate our conventions.

Individual works, unless they're highly integrated such as trilogy or larger works such as *Lord of the Rings* or *Harry Potter*, [get their own tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/31178).

The proper convention for this be to:

- retag the [riddick](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddick) question as [riddick-2013](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddick-2013) for clarity
- create a [riddick-franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddick-franchise) tag
- change [What is Riddick's middle name?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157579/what-is-riddicks-middle-name) to only have [riddick-franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddick-franchise)
- slowly over time add [riddick-franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddick-franchise) to the [the-chronicles-of-riddick](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-chronicles-of-riddick) questions (those 14 questions could be reasonably handled in 2-3 days)

*The Chronicles of Riddick* **is** the name of the franchise as a whole, but so is *Riddick*. Since both of these also happen to be names of individual works within the franchise, we add `-franchise` suffix to remove confusion. We've used that suffix before and it works fine, such as [alien-franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alien-franchise) (although `-trilogy` is more common, such as [nolan-batman-trilogy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nolan-batman-trilogy)).

Comment: Based on the votes and lack of alternatives, and that this is consistent with policy, I've started the process. `riddick-2013` and `riddick-franchise` are created, and the two `riddick` questions are fixed. Chronicles will come over time... like a chronicle.