# Do we need separate tags for "The Hunger Games" novels?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I've just noticed that we have the following tags: [the-hunger-games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hunger-games), [catching-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catching-fire), and [mockingjay](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mockingjay). I'm not familiar with this franchise, but it looks like the last two are individual novels within the series that is the first tag.

I think we have a general policy not to use individual works tags if the works are too closely related - this policy is in effect for [mass-effect](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect), [the-witcher](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher), [wheel-of-time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wheel-of-time), [the-expanse](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-expanse), [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter), [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire), and probably some others. The reasoning here is simple - it's unlikely that a question will be contained to a single novel, and it's very much possible that the answers will draw on the whole series/franchise if necessary.

There are some counterexamples I'm aware of - we have individual tags for *Lord of the Rings* novels (and *The Hobbit* films), as well as tags for each of the *Star Wars* films.

Question: **should individual novel tags within *The Hunger Games* franchise be merged into the [the-hunger-games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hunger-games) tag?**

Comment: There's also the problem of separate book and film tags for this franchise, but I don't know if they're different enough to warrant it (though our policy seems to require them regardless).

Comment: *edits title to "Should the individual [hunger-games] book tags be catching fire?"*

Comment: The books should be `[the-hunger-games]` and the film should be `[the-hunger-games-20XX]`, but then again I don't really know anything about this universe.

Answer (score 6):

As the site's [top expert](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/the-hunger-games/topusers) on the Hunger Games, I should probably weigh in on this.

**Individual-book tags are more useful in HG than in many other franchises.**

In *Lord of the Rings*, for example, the three books form a unified narrative, and I think *[citation needed]* Tolkien didn't even intend the story to be a trilogy. In *Harry Potter*, the seven books are separated by year and can be viewed as stories of their own, but there's a large extended universe around them and most of the HP questions don't relate to any particular book in the series.

In *The Hunger Games*, the three books are telling very different stories, and most questions are only relevant to one of them. The first book is the only one which covers a conventional Hunger Games, and it's not about much other than that. The second book covers the highly *un*conventional Quarter Quell, as well as the beginnings of a secret uprising. The third book is *totally* different, set mostly in District 13, all about open war rather than Games and subterfuge. Each book has a mostly different set of characters (rather necessary when most of the characters who appear in each book get killed off). Thus, it makes sense to tag, for example, questions about the war with [mockingjay](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mockingjay), questions about the Quarter Quell with [catching-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catching-fire), and questions about Cato or normal Hunger Games procedures with just [the-hunger-games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hunger-games).

**The tag for the first book is the same as the franchise tag ...**

This could be a potential issue, I'll admit. However, we're fortunate in that many of the general questions about the franchise are most relevant to the first book! Things like [How are multiple volunteers handled during the Reaping?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/50583/31394) or [Why are there so few volunteers in the Hunger Games?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/138723/31394) or [Why couldn't tributes keep the food from the Launch Room?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/124597/31394), which are about the Hunger Games as a whole, aren't so relevant to the second book (everything is different in the Quarter Quell) and not at all to the third book. So ambiguity between questions about the whole franchise and questions about the first book isn't *that* big of an issue. Also, since it's the *first* book, it can't spoil anything else. People reading book 1 might want to put the book 2 and 3 tags on ignore, but not vice versa.

**What about book vs film tags?**

Again, we're fortunate in that the films (which are, I'll come out and say it, an *excellent* adaptation) stuck reasonably close to the books. The first book and film are telling the same story with the same title; so are the second book and film; and the third and fourth films are both titled *Mockingjay* something, so they can fit under the [mockingjay](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mockingjay) tag together with the third book.

**TL;DR: as well as denoting different works of sci-fi, which [tend to get their own tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/31394), these tags also broadly categorise different types of question within the HG franchise.**

Answer (score 0):

## Burn 'em.

[catching-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catching-fire) has exactly 7 questions, while [mockinjay](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mockinjay) has 15. People have been doing fine without the individual work tags.

As well, any question may be answered with a quote or something from a different book (or the movie adaption).

Also... individual book tags are generally not any use, so I'd say just burn them with fire.

Comment: I don't really agree about all individual work tags, but in this case I agree less tags is easier to maintain and harder to apply wrongly.

Comment: Does this not run counter to this?  http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7924/31178 (I'm not sure, I've misunderstood that post before)

Comment: Agreed. Tags for individual books, movies, or TV shows are of no use.

Comment: "*any question may be answered with a quote or something from a different book*" - this is actually not so true for the HG franchise as for other things. The different books are pretty separate from each other in terms of the type of story they're telling.