# Add a new tag for Apple TV+ "For All Mankind" series?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

As I have understood (still new here), the current policy is that [all individual works get their own individual tag](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/31178); so, should we add a tag for the Apple TV+ alternate history series [For All Mankind](https://tv.apple.com/us/show/for-all-mankind/umc.cmc.6wsi780sz5tdbqcf11k76mkp7), debuted on November 1?

I have already asked the [first question on the series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223110/is-margo-madison-in-for-all-mankind-based-on-margaret-hamilton) (and, as it happens, I was able to answer it myself, after some research).

Comment: At 300 rep you gain the ability to create new tags; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags. If you're asking about something without an existing tag, feel free to create one.

Comment: @Valorum ooops... didn't know that I could create new tags with such a low rep (but I should have checked first before asking here)! Thanks for this, and also for actually creating the said tag (I have posted a first draft of a tag description)